# How to dynamically pass arguments to forms in django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms

I have a form 'BasicSearch', having two fields. One is a choice field called 'search_by' while the other is a text field called 'search_for'. I have models for customers, suppliers, items, projects and few others.
What I want to do is to give user the ability to perform their searches on various models on their respective pages by providing their query in the text field and selecting from the choice field what they want to search in (the column headers from the models)

I have already tried several solutions on stackoverflow but none is working for me. It works fine when I manually create a dictionary of column headers and pass it to the choice field.

Currently the search form class looks like below (Which is not working)

```
class BasicSearch(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self,arg):
        super(BasicSearch, self).__init__(arg)
        caller = arg
        if caller == 'customer':
            cu = Customers()
        field_dct = get_col_heads(cu)
        self.fields['search_by'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=field_dct,widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
        self.fields['search_for'] = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
```

The get_col_heads function:

```
def get_col_heads(cu):
    all_fields = cu._meta.fields
    all_field_list = []
    for fields in all_fields:
        column_head = (str(fields)).split(".")
        all_field_list.append(column_head[-1])
        field_list = all_field_list[1:-2]
        field_dct = tuple(zip(field_list,field_list))
    return field_dct
```

customers view class in view.py

```
class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'crudbasic/index.html'
    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context ['page_title'] = ''
        return context

class CustomerView(ListView):
    template_name = 'crudbasic/customers.html'
    model = Customers
    context_object_name = 'customer_data'

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['search_form'] = BasicSearch('customer')
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        search_form = BasicSearch(request.POST)
        if search_form.is_valid():
            data = request.POST.copy()
            qby = data.get('search_by')
            qstrting = data.get('search_for')
            queryparam = qby+'__'+'contains'
            search_list = Customers.objects.filter(**{queryparam:qstrting})
            customer_data = search_list
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'customer_data': customer_data,'search_form':search_form})
```

When I put an **init** inside my form field, in order to take the argument for the selecting the respective model/table and then generate dictionary from the table column headers, it all went haywire. currently with the code above it is giving me the following error.

```
AttributeError at /customers/
'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Please help if anyone knows a way to do it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your custom `__init__` method of the `BasicSearch` form class disrespects all the other arguments which a form can have. You can't do this. A more appropriate way is to use a custom `kwarg` argument something like this:

```
class BasicSearch(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        caller = kwargs.pop('caller')
        super(BasicSearch, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # ...


# usage
form = BasicSearch(caller='customer')

# usage with POST
form = BasicSearch(request.POST,  caller='customer')
```

PS. In python everything is an object, even the classes, so instead of giving a `"string"` as a caller, you can just pass the class itself: `form = BasicSearch(caller=Customers)`

Comment: Thank you, It worked like a charm, So that means you cannot pass a simple argument to an init function. And your suggestion of passing the Customers directly seems to be more appropriate in this case. I will use that, thanks once again. I had been thinking about it since last night, couldn't figure out what was going wrong.